# C# Sleep Detection PowerModeChanged

Tags: c#

I want me program to write to the console when the computer it going to sleep but am unable to do so. I think I am setting this up wrong. Here is what I have...

Edit: New .cs file

```
using LightFX;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using ConsoleApplication3;

namespace SampleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
           
        }

        SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += PowerModeChanged;
    }
    class PowerModeChanged
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: this not working? - http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/DetectPowerEvents.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That event is raised by the [`SystemEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx) class (it's a static event). You just need to bind to it:

```
SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerModeChanged;
```

You need to do this somewhere in your main method.

And, of course, delete your custom delegate, since it's already defined by the framework. You don't need this line:

> <s>public static event PowerModeChangedEventHandler
>   PowerModeChanged;</s>

UPDATE:

```
    static void Main()
    {
       SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerModeChanged;
       Console.ReadLine(); //just wait, don't exit immediately.
    }

    private static void OnPowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        //Handle the event here.
    }
```

Comment: When I put this " SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += PowerModeChanged;" I get an error on the .PowerModeChanged that says it is an event that is used as a type.  What does this mean?

Comment: @jister: Have you deleted your event definition yet? Also, you may want to consider renaming the event handler/method `PowerModeChanged` to `OnPowerModeChanged`.

Comment: I have updated my post with what I have now...  Still have an error saying .PowerModeChanged is an event but is used like a type

Comment: @jister: See update. It strikes me that you are not very familiar with basic C# programming, nor with the event based programming model. Perhaps you should do a bit of reading on that before proceeding.

Comment: Don't create a console application for this, just use a Windows Forms application that does not create/show any forms. Much easier to keep running, and doesn't show the unnecessary console window.

Comment: Its been 2 years since I have touched c# or c in general, so I am getting back into the swing of things...

Answer (score 1):

You have mabye found what you looking for, but still..
This code works for me:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;


class Powerstatus
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged +=
        new PowerModeChangedEventHandler(SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Mode);
}

}
```