# How to do a set of tasks before system goes for sleep in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to save some users work before system goes for sleep so after making some research I came to know about **SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged** but with this event my program is not completing the saving users work and before that only system is going for sleep.So how should I handle this scenario ?

Comment: Doesn't sleep modus automatically save whatever you're doing so you can continue immediately once you leave sleep mode?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs but I want to do some custom things(eg Saving the time at which sytem went for sleep etc) before system goes for sleep.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747146/c-sharp-win32-sleep-detection-powermodechanged

Comment: @yogi its not the duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747146/c-sharp-win32-sleep-detection-powermodechanged in my case my action is getting called when system goes for sleep but its not able to complete.

Comment: The problem is that sleep mode just puts your computer to sleep, which I think means that there is no guarantee that your code will actually finish running. I think a better option would be to run your code when the machine LEAVES sleep, if at all possible.

Comment: OS pauses what it does and cuts most power for hardware. You should not do something important at this state because OS will not wait for your application.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Thanks,Your answer is really promising.Is there any way by which I will come know at what time system went for sleep ?Since for my current work that time really matters.

Comment: You can save time in variable at this point - it stays in RAM and after resuming you can use variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
ManagementEventWatcher eventWatcher = new System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher();
WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("Win32_PowerManagementEvent"); //catch power change events
eventWatcher.Query = query;
eventWatcher.EventArrived += new System.Management.EventArrivedEventHandler(eventWatcher_EventArrived); // rgister the event handler
eventWatcher.Start(); // start the event watcher
```

Handler:

```
void eventWatcher_EventArrived(object sender, System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
        int eventType = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties["EventType"].Value);
        switch (eventType)
        {
            case 4://sleep                       
                    break;
            case 7://resume
                break;
        }
}
```

Note: Do not forget to stop watcher when your program exits.

```
if(eventWatcher != null)
     eventWatcher.Stop();
```

More Details ...

http://cmehmet6parmak.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/catch-computer-sleep-event-c-windows-7/

Comment: Do OS wait till application finish its work before sleeping? I guess not.

Comment: @Reniuz OS will not wait till the applications finishes its work.

Comment: I have tried this myself and when supposedly resuming after sleep, I got 18 as EventType. What does it refer to? or when can I find a list of codes? this seems like mission impossible -_-